# docxtpl special tr tag {%tr %} is not working

Tags: python-3.x, ms-word, jinja2, python-docx, docxtpl

Hi i am using docxtpl to generate the MS Word documents from python using JINJA template engine, I checked [this](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#extensions) documentation which says we can use special tags for table rows, columns and paragraphs but i am not able to generate table rows dynamically.

**First i tried the following way**

```
{% for name in rows %}
{{ name }}
{% endfor %}
```

[image: The template screenshot]

But it adds all items in the same row no new generated.

**then i tried the following way as mentioned in the above mentioned documentation.**

```
{%tr for name in rows %}
{{ name }}
{%tr endfor %}
```

but it generates the following error

> Encountered unknown tag 'endfor'.

**then i tried the following way, it works but it some how change the generated document margins, formats and styles . all document just mess up visually .**

```
row = self.document.tables[3].add_row().cells # add row
row[0].text = '' #add empty text to create paragraph
row[0].paragraphs[0].add_run('Some value') #use run to add value
row[0].paragraphs[0].style = self.document.tables[3].row_cells(3)[1].paragraphs[0].style
#this line copy the style of previous row cell to the current row cell else styles are not preserved
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second attempt with the `%tr` tag is correct, but it is possible that it is not in the correct format in your template document.

Try using that `for` loop in this format in your template:
[image: template screenshot]

Using that template I generated this output:
[image: output]

I was able to figure this out based on [this issue](https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/issues/31) on the Github repo which pointed me to [this test](https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/master/tests/order.py) and this [test template](https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/master/tests/templates/order_tpl.docx).

Comment: Yes it worked, the format was not right